# When Tkinter Frame class too long, event "configure" stop tracking it

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey guys I'm working on a image reading GUI using Tkinter, trying to make a auto resize frame in canvas, and it's scrollbar should renew when new image add into frame.
 I found a really helpful example on web and I modified it to a more general one:

```
import Tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (1400,807,0,0))

scrollable = ScrollableFrame(root)
scrollable.pack( fill = Tkinter.BOTH)
image_container = []
for i in range (50):
    # Here's the problem! Scrollbar works properly, but after scroll down to 50000
    # units, is screen stop at 50000, and when scroll up back to lower than 50000,
    # it works again !!!!
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage( Image.open("%s.jpg"%(i)) ) )
    image_container.append( Tkinter.Label( scrollable.interior, image = img )
    image_container[ len( image_container ) -1 ].image = img




class ScrollableFrame(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        self.set_parameter( kw )
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)

        # create a canvas object and a vertical scrollbar for scrolling it

        self.scrollbar = Tkinter.Scrollbar(self, orient= self.par["orient"])
        self.scrollbar.pack(fill= self.par["scroll_fill"], side= self.par["scroll_side"], expand=Tkinter.FALSE)

        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, bg = self.par["canvas_bg"] )
        if self.par["orient"] in ("vertical",Tkinter.VERTICAL):
            self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar.set )
            self.scrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        else:
            self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand = self.scrollbar.set )
            self.scrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.pack(side= self.par["canvas_side"], fill=Tkinter.BOTH, expand=Tkinter.TRUE)

        # reset the view
        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        self.interior = interior = Tkinter.Frame(self.canvas, bg = self.par["canvas_bg"])
        interior_id = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
                                           anchor="nw")

        # track changes to the canvas and frame width and sync them,
        # also updating the scrollbar
        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
            print size, "interior"
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
            if self.par["orient"] in ("vertical",Tkinter.VERTICAL):
                if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                    # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                    self.canvas.config(width=interior.winfo_reqwidth())
            else:
                if interior.winfo_reqheight() != self.canvas.winfo_height():
                    # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                    self.canvas.config(height=interior.winfo_reqheight())

        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)

        def _configure_canvas(event):
            print "canvas"
            if self.par["orient"] in ("vertical",Tkinter.VERTICAL):
                if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                    # update the inner frame's width to fill the canvas
                    self.canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=self.canvas.winfo_width())
            else:
                if interior.winfo_reqheight() != self.canvas.winfo_height():
                    # update the inner frame's height to fill the canvas
                    self.canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, height=self.canvas.winfo_height())
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)

    def set_parameter(self, options):
        self.par = {"orient": "vertical",
                    "canvas_bg":"white"}
        if "orient" in options.keys():
            self.par["orient"] = options["orient"]
            options.pop("orient")
        if "canvas_bg" in options.keys():
            self.par["canvas_bg"] = options["canvas_bg"]
            options.pop("canvas_bg")
        if self.par["orient"] in ("vertical",Tkinter.VERTICAL):
            self.par["scroll_fill"] = Tkinter.Y
            self.par["scroll_side"] = Tkinter.RIGHT
            self.par["canvas_side"] = Tkinter.LEFT
        else:
            self.par["scroll_fill"] = Tkinter.X
            self.par["scroll_side"] = Tkinter.BOTTOM
            self.par["canvas_side"] = Tkinter.TOP
```

This work fine at first, but when I load about 40 images, the frame height goes over 50000( units) and the configure don't works! Just can't find out what's wrong here, is there a system limit height?

Comment: You didn't quite get all of your code highlighted properly

Comment: Sorry, I've add more description now.